# ASP.NET AJAX is not rendering a __cultureInfo JS object for en-US locales

Tags: asp.net, ajax, localization, cultureinfo, scriptmanager

I'm using the **ASP.NET AJAX  control** on my site and have enabled the following settings on the ScriptManager:

```
scriptManager.EnableScriptGlobalization = true;
scriptManager.EnableScriptLocalization = true;
```

When I switch the browser language to, say, French, I get a rich JavaScript object rendered on the page called **__cultureInfo** that contains all the good stuff I need to initialize date pickers and to properly format date strings.

However, when the locale is US English, the **__cultureInfo** object isn't rendered.

Is there a way to force ASP.NET AJAX to render this JavaScript variable / object for **all** locales? I want to initialize all of my locale-aware controls without having to special-case US English.

Comment: Well, while I'm waiting for a definitive answer, I've gone ahead and made wrapper for members that are missing in "en-US": locale.getFirstDayOfWeek(), locale.getName(), and locale.getLongDatePattern(). I'm checking to see if "typeof(__cultureInfo) === 'undefined'". If so, then I return hard-coded values for English. This works but is really klunky.

Comment: I encounter this issue today also, and cost me several hours:

"ClientCultureInfo.GetClientCultureScriptBlock(CultureInfo cultureInfo)" have the following code snip:

`Type type = (cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat == null) ? null : cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.GetType();
    if (cultureInfo.Equals(enUS) && (type == typeof(GregorianCalendar)))
    {
        return null;
    }`

If the current thread's culture is "en-US" , seems that the "var __cultureInfo = " will not be rendered by ScriptManager, I am not sure why MS do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft clones the Invarient culture to en-US so even though __cultureInfo is not loaded you should have everything you need in **Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture**

```
switch(typeof(cultureInfo)) {
case "string":
    // this is true when the server is 3.5
    cultureInfo = window.eval("(" + cultureInfo + ")");
    // allow fallthrough to object
case "object":
    this.CurrentCulture = this._parse(cultureInfo);
    delete __cultureInfo;
    break;
default:
    cultureInfo = clone(invariant);
    // fix up the differences
    cultureInfo.name = "en-US";
    cultureInfo.numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "$";
    var dtf = cultureInfo.dateTimeFormat;
    dtf.FullDatePattern = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt";
    dtf.LongDatePattern = "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy";
    dtf.LongTimePattern = "h:mm:ss tt";
    dtf.ShortDatePattern = "M/d/yyyy";
    dtf.ShortTimePattern = "h:mm tt";
    dtf.YearMonthPattern = "MMMM, yyyy";
    this.CurrentCulture = this._parse(cultureInfo);
    break;
}
```